# Segmentation fault by passing arguments to a function (C, codeblocks on linux)

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

Why do i keep getting "segmentation fault (core dumped)" by running this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d", strlen(argc));

    return 0;
}
```

That's my "argc"

```
gnome-terminal --disable-factory -t Es1 -x  /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /.../Lab1/Es1/bin/Debug/Es1 Es1.cbp es1file.txt es1out.txt (in /.../Lab1/Es1/.)
```

Comment: `argc` is an integer, not a pointer to a character string.

Comment: Before posting a question try to do some work and try to solve yourself. This is a simple one because 90% of the developers know that strlen() is related to string length and not related to integer.

Answer (score 4):

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
```

The strlen() function takes a pointer to character string. and you are passing an integer to it.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `argc` isn't a string, it's an *integer* value. The name `argc` stands for "argument count", and tells you the number of entries in the `argv` array.

Using `argc` as a pointer to a string leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which often results in crashes. Really, using *anything* that is not a pointer to a string as argument to a function which expects a pointer to a string will lead to undefined behavior.

Don't you get a warning about it? Then you need to enable more warnings when compiling! You should get a warning telling you that you are "making a pointer from integer without cast" (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

`argc` is an `int`eger, but `strlen()` expects a pointer to a string (`char *`), that's why you get a Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 0):

1°) strlen, as its name clearly states, gives you the length of a string. Here, you're trying to use it on a int : argc. (Which gives you the length of the argument array argv).

In C, strings are arrays of characters terminated by the "\0" character. Strlen will only work safely if you use on such an array (if the array do not have a "\0" ending character, you'll get the same error).

2°) If you want to display the number of arguments, simply use argc (as in "argument count") minus one (since the name of the program will be the first argument).

3°) If you want to display the length of one argument, you'll need to specify the argument and then use strlen. E.g. :

```
if (argc > 1) {
   printf("%d", strlen(argv[1]));
}
```